# Error on Civi upgrade to 4.6.10 on Wordpress

Tags: upgrade

TypeError: CRM.$ is not a functionhttp://mygriefandloss.org/wp/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fupgrade%2Fqueue%2Frunner&reset=1&qrid=CRM_Upgrade line 284

Comment: I have Determined this to have something to do with incorrect paths.  Modified civicrm.setting.php to add the directory, then update went smoothly however, when I try to use civicrm, I am logged out.